# Why does Python HTTPServer.shutdown not actually shutdown the server?

Tags: python, server, shutdown

Consider a toy server serving a notification that it will quit in 5s at `http://localhost:48555/q` and 'Hello World' elsewhere.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import urlparse

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        path =urlparse(self.path).path
        response=f"{datetime.now()}: {'stopping server in 5s' if path=='/q' else 'Hello World!'}"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(response, 'ascii'))
        self.wfile.flush()
        if path=='/q':
            Thread(target=self.quit()).start()
    def quit(self):  # don't call on thread running the server
        sleep(5)
        self.server.shutdown()

address = ('localhost', 48555)
server = HTTPServer(address, Handler)
print(f'started a server on http://{address[0]}:{address[1]}')
server.serve_forever()
```

Despite calling `self.server.shutdown()` from a separate thread, the server doesn't shutdown correctly - the tab in the browser (Firefox 115.0.2) stays in loading state while the python environment keeps running. Also the response is never written to client in spite of the explicit `flush`.

**Why is this happening?**

I have tried making the thread `daemon=True`, removing the `sleep` altogether and replacing
`server.shutdown` with `exit()`. Only the last one actually shuts everything down, though the reponse is still served *afterwards*, not before the wait.